# Drawing a graph in the corner of another

Tags: r, graphics, plot

How should I present a small plot in the corner of another plot in R?

Comment: With ggplot2, see the last example in `?annotation_custom`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done this using something like this:

```
# Making some fake data
plot1 <- data.frame(x=sample(x=1:10,10,replace=FALSE),
                    y=sample(x=1:10,10,replace=FALSE))
plot2 <- data.frame(x=sample(x=1:10,10,replace=FALSE),
                    y=sample(x=1:10,10,replace=FALSE))
plot3 <- data.frame(x=sample(x=1:10,10,replace=FALSE),
                    y=sample(x=1:10,10,replace=FALSE))

layout(matrix(c(2,1,1,3,1,1),2,3,byrow=TRUE))
plot(plot1$x,plot1$y)
plot(plot2$x,plot2$y)
plot(plot3$x,plot3$y)
```

The `matrix` and `layout` commands let you arrange multiple graphs into a single plot. Basically, you put the number of each plot (in the order you are going to call it) into each cell, and then whatever the arrangement is ends up being how your plots are laid out. For instance, in the case above, `matrix(c(2,1,1,3,1,1),byrow=TRUE)` results in a matrix that looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    1
[2,]    3    1    1
```

So, you can end up with something like this:

[image: Example Multiplot]

EDITED TO ADD:

Okay, so, if you want to integrate a plot in the corner, you can do that using the same `layout` command by simply changing the matrix. For instance, this is different code:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,1,1,1),2,3,byrow=TRUE))
plot1 <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=c(9,10,8,7,3,4,1,2,5,6))
plot2 <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=c(6,7,5,1,2,8,3,10,9,4))
plot(plot1$x,plot1$y,type="o",col="red")
plot(plot2$x,plot2$y,type="o",xlab="",ylab="",main="",sub="",col="blue")
```

And the resultant matrix is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    1    1    1
```

The plot that comes out looks like this:

[image: Example Multiplot 2]

Comment: @TAReham thanks and if I want a small plot inside of another?

Comment: @TAReham for axample a small plot just topleft and inside of another plot?

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is already closed, but I'm throwing this example up for posterity.

You can do custom visualizations like this quite easily with the base 'grid' package once you get the basics down.  Here is a quick example of some custom functions I use along with a demo of plotting data.

[image: example plot]

---

**Custom functions**

---

```
# Function to initialize a plotting area.
init_Plot <- function(
    .df,
    .x_Loc, 
    .y_Loc, 
    .justify, 
    .width, 
    .height
    ){

    # Initialize plotting area to fit data.
    # We have to turn off clipping to make it
    # easy to plot the labels around the plot.
    pushViewport(viewport(xscale=c(min(.df[,1]), max(.df[,1])), yscale=c(min(0,min(.df[,-1])), max(.df[,-1])), x=.x_Loc, y=.y_Loc, width=.width, height=.height, just=.justify, clip="off", default.units="npc"))

    # Color behind text.
    grid.rect(x=0, y=0, width=unit(axis_CEX, "lines"), height=1, default.units="npc", just=c("right", "bottom"), gp=gpar(fill=space_Background, col=space_Background))
    grid.rect(x=0, y=1, width=1, height=unit(title_CEX, "lines"), default.units="npc", just=c("left", "bottom"), gp=gpar(fill=space_Background, col=space_Background))

    # Color in the space.
    grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill=chart_Fill, col=chart_Col))
}

# Function to finalize and label a plotting area.
finalize_Plot <- function(
    .df, 
    .plot_Title
    ){

    # Label plot using the internal reference
    # system, instead of the parent window, so
    # we always have perfect placement.
    grid.text(.plot_Title, x=0.5, y=1.05, just=c("center","bottom"), rot=0, default.units="npc", gp=gpar(cex=title_CEX))
    grid.text(paste(names(.df)[-1], collapse=" & "), x=-0.05, y=0.5, just=c("center","bottom"), rot=90, default.units="npc", gp=gpar(cex=axis_CEX))
    grid.text(names(.df)[1], x=0.5, y=-0.05, just=c("center","top"), rot=0, default.units="npc", gp=gpar(cex=axis_CEX))

    # Finalize plotting area.
    popViewport()
}

# Function to plot a filled line chart of
# the data in a data frame.  The first column
# of the data frame is assumed to be the
# plotting index, with each column being a
# set of y-data to plot.  All data is assumed
# to be numeric.
plot_Line_Chart <- function(
    .df,
    .x_Loc,
    .y_Loc,
    .justify,
    .width,
    .height,
    .colors,
    .plot_Title
    ){

    # Initialize plot.
    init_Plot(.df, .x_Loc, .y_Loc, .justify, .width, .height)

    # Calculate what value to use as the
    # return for the polygons.
    y_Axis_Min <- min(0, min(.df[,-1]))

    # Plot each set of data as a polygon,
    # so we can fill it in with color to
    # make it easier to read.
    for (i in 2:ncol(.df)){
        grid.polygon(x=c(min(.df[,1]),.df[,1], max(.df[,1])), y=c(y_Axis_Min,.df[,i], y_Axis_Min), default.units="native", gp=gpar(fill=.colors[i-1], col=.colors[i-1], alpha=1/ncol(.df)))
    }

    # Draw plot axes.
    grid.lines(x=0, y=c(0,1), default.units="npc")
    grid.lines(x=c(0,1), y=0, default.units="npc")

    # Finalize plot.
    finalize_Plot(.df, .plot_Title)

}
```

---

**Demo code**

---

```
grid.newpage()

# Specify main chart options.
chart_Fill = "lemonchiffon"
chart_Col = "snow3"
space_Background = "white"
title_CEX = 1.4
axis_CEX = 1

plot_Line_Chart(data.frame(time=1:1860, EuStockMarkets)[1:5], .x_Loc=1, .y_Loc=0, .just=c("right","bottom"), .width=0.9, .height=0.9, c("dodgerblue", "deeppink", "green", "red"), "EU Stocks")

# Specify sub-chart options.
chart_Fill = "lemonchiffon"
chart_Col = "snow3"
space_Background = "lemonchiffon"
title_CEX = 0.8
axis_CEX = 0.7

for (i in 1:4){
    plot_Line_Chart(data.frame(time=1:1860, EuStockMarkets)[c(1,i + 1)], .x_Loc=0.15*i, .y_Loc=0.8, .just=c("left","top"), .width=0.1, .height=0.1, c("dodgerblue", "deeppink", "green", "red")[i], "EU Stocks")
}
```

Comment: Wow. That definitely makes my response look pretty weaksauce in comparison. :)

Comment: @TARehman The main difference, though, is that the `par` method in your answer can accept the base plotting functions, whereas the 'grid' method will require you to specify your own plotting methods.  It's mainly a question of time and just how customized your plot needs to be.

Comment: The question isn't closed and the OP definitely has the ability to change their choice as to which answer gets the checkmark.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `par(fig=..., new=TRUE)`.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
hist( x, col = "light blue" )
par( fig = c(.7, .95, .7, .95), mar=.1+c(0,0,0,0), new = TRUE )
qqnorm(x, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", main="")
qqline(x, col="blue", lwd=2)
box()
```

[image: smaller plot in a corner]

Comment: I like this option a lot for it's simplicity and ability to use the base plotting functions.  Being a 'grid' user, I don't have use for it myself, but I'll have to remember this for others who ask.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 6):

The `subplot` function in the TeachingDemos package does exactly this for base graphics.

Create the full sized plot, then call `subplot` with the plotting command that you want in the subplot and specify the location of the subplot.  The location can be specified by keyword such as "topleft" or you can give it the coordinates in the current plots user coordinate system.